# Reference to database and/or server name in 'DBname.dbo.TableName' is not supported in this version of SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure

I'm inserting data from a Universal Windows APP to a Database in Azure.
I can make "Select" queries but now that I'm trying to insert data I have the error above.
I create a new Table with only one varchar type field to make sure everything else is right, but can't even insert a single string.
My query is something like

```
INSERT INTO [DBName].[dbo].[TableName] ([test]) VALUES (@String)
```

I add the parameters with

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@String",object.data.data2.ToString());
```

Comment: For future reference, post the **complete and actual** error message. It sounds like the error comes from your app and not from sql server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is telling you not to include the database name. So... don't:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName] ([test]) VALUES (@String)
```

Or (removing the schema too):

```
INSERT INTO [TableName] ([test]) VALUES (@String)
```

Comment: Already try with:
-[serverName].[DBName].[dbo].[TableName]  
-[DBName].[dbo].[TableName]   
-[dbo].[TableName]   
-[TableName] 
And still didn't work. Now the error is "invalid object name". Already check the schema of my table and it is "dbo". Do I need to modify the schema or include anything about the schema in my query?

Comment: @Marco19 it sounds to me like the table isn't there. Are you absolutely sure you're connecting to the right place and that the table exists in that place? Treble check...

Comment: You're absolutely right, I had a typo with my database and even't had check it worrying about schemas. Thanks.

Comment: @marco19 we've all been there